# UnicodeDecodeError on import (tweepy)

Tags: python, unicode, tweepy

Im trying to use the function "update_profile_background_image" in tweepy and are getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXX.py", line 1401, in <module>
    psn_card.gen_twitter_bg(user_db)
  File "XXX.py", line 972, in gen_twitter_bg
    auth_api.update_profile_background_image(file)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/api.py", line 346, in update_profile_background_image
    headers, post_data = API._pack_image(filename, 800)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/api.py", line 729, in _pack_image
    body = '\r\n'.join(body)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

the problem is: this lib is inside a egg file, how i solve this problem ?
Is this a bug on tweepy ?

The function is to read a file (image) and sends via POST (http) to the twitter api.

The error occurs at the point where I try to manipulate the loaded image.

All my .py are configure to use utf-8 :

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
```

Comment: more information please. what does your call of update_profile_background_image() look like? The error may be there, we can't tell yet.

Comment: General link which may be of use: http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that `filename` is a Unicode string. Unfortunately Tweepy does not support Unicode filenames. Is this a bug? Arguably.

The problem is it tries to create the HTTP POST data using the Unicode string verbatim, instead of encoding it down to a byte string:

```
body.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="%s"' % filename)
```

This makes one string in the `body` list a Unicode string, and when one string in a sequence is a Unicode string and you try to `join()` them the result ends up being Unicode. However an HTTP POST body is a byte string with a load of binary gunk in, so it's not ASCII-compatible and so makes the attempt to implicitly coerce it to Unicode fail.

(In any case, the filename given in `Content-Disposition` definitely shouldn't contain a complete path, as the above code does. I would suggest something like `filename= os.path.basename(filename).encode('us-ascii', 'ignore')` in the line before the above as a first quick fix. I'm not sure that Twitter even cares what the filename is, though...)